# RE return time span as a double in if statement

Tags: c#, timespan

Re my question about time span before. What I am trying to do. I am trying to auto update my text box then time elapses. And with code below it works just fine:

```
public  void AutoSaveTimer()
{
   timer = new System.Timers.Timer ();
   timer.AutoReset= false ;
   timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler (timer_Elapsed);
   timer .Interval = GetInterval();
   timer.Start ();
}

public  double GetInterval()
{      
   DateTime now = DateTime .Now;
   return ((60-now.Second )*1000-now.Millisecond );
}

public void timer_Elapsed ( object sender ,System .Timers .ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   UpdateLogDatabase();

   timer .Interval =GetInterval ();
   timer .Start ();
}

private void AutoSaveTimerStop()
{
   timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   timer.Stop();
}
```

But if I try to check user options in if statement the method is not returning double I am getting error: Use of unassigned variable.

```
  public double GetInterval()
  {
      double d;
      DateTime now = new DateTime();

      if (cb5Min.Checked== true)
      {
          d= ((60 - now.Second) * 1000 - now.Millisecond);
      }
      else if (cb15Min.Checked)
      {
          d= ((900 - now.Second) * 1000 - now.Millisecond);
      }
      return d;
  }
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: The error indicates that both the if evaluations are failing i.e. cb5Min.Checked && cb15Min.Checked == false

Comment: Initialize your  double d to 0.0.

Comment: I guess you have erroneously set both the conditions (if ... else) to same (true) and the program execution ends with returning "d" as unassigned. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting error: Use of unassigned variable.

You are trying to return your variable `d` from your method, you have declare it but haven't initialized it, initialization is done in the if block and compiler can't determine if that part of code would be reached. So its better if you can assign some default value to `d` like:

```
double d = 0;
```

or in your code you can use another else block to ensure that `d` is initialized to some value before being returned.

Comment: I tried to set to 0; and i was gettig error: '0' is not a valid value for 'Interval'. 'Interval' must be greater than 0.

Comment: @user2064345, thats an exception not an error. Also I think you need to re look at your code and make sure that you are getting some interval, Currently your both case of if statements are failing and that is why you are not getting the right interval for the timer

Comment: Say I did this but it is throwing exception again (checkbox is checked) :  if ( cb5Min.Checked && cb15Min.Checked ==false )

Comment: @user2064345, you can't set `0` as the timer interval, that is why the exception. You are not getting the right value for `d` in your method `GetInterval`, fix your method to return correct value, or assign a default value to `d` something greater than 0;

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting error: Use of unassigned variable.

Try to learn to understand compiler errors. If both checkboxes are not checked, you return an unassigned `d`. You'd better initialize `d` where you declare it, for example to `0`.

Comment: I tried to set to 0; and i was gettig error: '0' is not a valid value for 'Interval'. 'Interval' must be greater than 0.